# preg_replace removing single/double-character words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this line

```
$txt=preg_replace('#\s(\S){1,2}\s#',' ',$txt);
```

Which i wanted to remove all the single and double character words (a, no, do etc...).

It works, but not perfectly - when i have strings which look like that:

```
xxxxx a b c d e xxxxx
```

then my code leaves something like this (every second word that matches, is ommited)

```
xxxxx b d xxxxx
```

I understand that preg match sees it like " a ", "b", " c ", "d", " e ", so is there any simple way to fix that? I thought about duplicating every whitespace but maybe someone would have a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a repeating non-capturing group around the segments that are repeating, like this:

```
$txt = preg_replace('#(?:\s+\S{1,2})+\s+#',' ',$txt);
```

I also removed the unnecessary capturing group around `\S`, since you don't use or need it, and it won't capture correctly when it's repeated.

You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/GWjtYK).

Comment: didn't work, but You gave me a great clue, i repeated space-char-char section and ended it with space and now it goes well. `#(\s(\S){1,2})+\s#` thanks!

Comment: @cyborg - That should work, I've updated my answer accordingly, including removing the capturing groups when you don't need them.

Comment: ok, now it's better but i have to stay with my code above, cause while you use special characters like ą ę ż ź ć there is a little mess. thanks for your help